# How to prove $ ((S\times_A T)(1))_{(f\otimes g)}\cong S(1)_{(f)}\otimes_{S_{(f)}}(S\times_A T)_{(f\otimes g)}\otimes_{T_{(g)}} T(1)_{(g)}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, projective-schemes, quasicoherent-sheaves

I'm currently trying to solve Exercise 5.11 in chapter 2 of Hartshorne: Let $S,T$ be $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$-graded rings with $S_0=T_0=A$, and define their *Cartesian product* $S\times_A T$ to be
$$
S\times_A T=\bigoplus_{d\geq 0}S_d\otimes_A T_d.
$$
I already showed that $\operatorname{Proj}(S\times_A T)\cong \operatorname{Proj}(S)\times_{\operatorname{Spec}(A)}\operatorname{Proj}(T)$. Now I am trying to show that
$$
\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Proj}(S\times_A T)}\cong p_1^{*}\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Proj}(S)}\otimes p_2^{*}\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Proj}(T)}
$$
where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are the structure maps making $\operatorname{Proj}(S\times_A T)$ the product of $\operatorname{Proj}(S)$ and $\operatorname{Proj}(T)$. I'm stuck at the following very specific part of the proof:

Is it true that
$$
((S\times_A T)(1))_{(f\otimes g)}\cong S(1)_{(f)}\otimes_{S_{(f)}}(S\times_A T)_{(f\otimes g)}\otimes_{T_{(g)}} T(1)_{(g)}
$$
For all $f\in S_d$ and $g\in T_d$ where $d\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ is arbitrary? I constructed a map going from right to left by mapping $s/f^n\otimes[(s'\otimes t')/(f\otimes g)^n]\otimes t/g^n$ to $((ss')\otimes (tt'))/(f\otimes g)^{2n}$ and showed that it is surjective. However, I'm struggling to prove that the map is injective.

**Edit:** As suggested by KReiser, I tried to directly construct an inverse. However, I'm only able to do this under the extra assumption that $S$ and $T$ are generated by $S_1$ resp. $T_1$ as $A$-algebras, so that we can assume that $f$ and $g$ are of degree $1$. Here's why.

To justify the well-definedness of the map
$$
((S\times_A T)(1))_{(f\otimes g)}\to S(1)_{(f)}\otimes_{S_{(f)}}(S\times_A T)_{(f\otimes g)}\otimes_{T_{(g)}}T(1)_{(g)}\\
(s\otimes t)/(f\otimes g)^n\mapsto (s/f^n)\otimes 1\otimes (t/g^n)
$$
we would like to start by defining it on the homogeneous pieces of $(S\times_A T)(1)$ and then pass to the localisation. However, for this to work, we would have to relax the target to $S(1)_{f}\otimes_{S_{(f)}}(S\times_A T)_{f\otimes g}\otimes_{T_{(g)}}T(1)_{g}$, and only afterwards show that the image is contained in $S(1)_{(f)}\otimes_{S_{(f)}}(S\times_A T)_{(f\otimes g)}\otimes_{T_{(g)}}T(1)_{(g)}$, because otherwise, the map
$$
s\otimes t\in (S\times_A T)(1)\mapsto (s/1)\otimes 1\otimes (t/1)
$$
wouldn't be well-defined. So at this point we have a map of abelian groups $(S\times_A T)(1)\to S(1)_{f}\otimes_{S_{(f)}}(S\times_A T)_{f\otimes g}\otimes_{T_{(g)}}T(1)_{g}$. Now to pass to the localisation on the source, as we have only a morphism of abelian groups at this point, we would have to justify by hand why it is well defined. That is, we want to show that if $(s\otimes t)/(f\otimes g)^n$ is equal to $0$ inside $(S\times_A T)(1)_{f\otimes g}$, then $(s/1)\otimes 1\otimes (t/1)$ is $0$ inside $S(1)_{f}\otimes_{S_{(f)}}(S\times_A T)_{f\otimes g}\otimes_{T_{(g)}}T(1)_{g}$. If we now suppose that $f$ and $g$ are of degree $1$, then this can be done: if $e$ is the degree of $s$ and $t$, then
$$
(s/1)\otimes 1\otimes (t/1)=((s/f^{e+1})sf^{e+1})\otimes 1\otimes ((t/g^{e+1})tg^{e+1})=\\
=(sf^{e+1}/1)\otimes ((s\otimes t)/(f\otimes g)^{e+1})\otimes (tg^{e+1}/1)=0
$$
because of the middle term. However, I don't see how to do this without assuming that $f$ and $g$ are of degree $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about constructing an inverse directly? If $(s\otimes t)/(f\otimes g)^d$ is an element of $(S\times_A T)(1)_{(f\otimes g)}$, send it to $s/f^d \otimes 1 \otimes t/g^d$. To see that this is mutually inverse with your map, we just need to do a little calculation. The first composition is relatively straightforward:

$$(s\otimes t)/(f\otimes g)^d \mapsto s/f^d \otimes 1 \otimes t/g^d = s/f^d \otimes [(f\otimes g)^d/(f\otimes g)^d] \otimes t/g^d \\ \mapsto (sf^d\otimes tg^d)/(f\otimes g)^{2d} = (s\otimes t)/(f\otimes g)^d.$$

The second direction requires a small tensor manipulation:

$$s/f^n \otimes [(s'\otimes t')/(f\otimes g)^n] \otimes t/g^n \mapsto (ss'\otimes tt')/(f\otimes g)^{2n} \\\mapsto ss'/f^{2n} \otimes 1 \otimes tt'/g^{2n} = s/f^n \otimes [(s'/f^n \otimes 1)\cdot (1\otimes t'/g^n)] \otimes t/g^n$$

where we used that $s'/f^n$ and $t'/g^n$ are actually elements of $S_{(f)}$ and $T_{(g)}$ so they can be pulled across the tensor product.

The lesson here is that sometimes it can be easier to write down an inverse map than to check bijectivity directly.

---

**Edit**: Since your troubles aren't quite resolved, let's write down a more explicit construction and check we don't need $f,g$ of degree one, just that they're the same degree.

Start with the map $S_d\times T_d \to S(1)_f \otimes_{S_{(f)}} (S\times_A T)_{f\otimes g} \otimes_{T_{(g)}} T(1)_g$ defined by $(s,t)\mapsto s\otimes 1 \otimes t$. This is $A$-bilinear, as $A$ sits naturally inside the degree zero parts of $S_{(f)}$, $T_{(g)}$, and $(S\times_A T)_{f\otimes g}$, and the map clearly respects addition. So we get that our map factors through $S_d\otimes_A T_d$. Taking direct sums, we get a map $S\times_A T\to S(1)_f \otimes_{S_{(f)}} (S\times_A T)_{f\otimes g} \otimes_{T_{(g)}} T(1)_g$ defined on pure tensors by $s\otimes t\mapsto s\otimes 1 \otimes t$.

Next, we check that the action of $f\otimes g$ on $S\times_A T$ is invertible on the target: $f\otimes 1 \otimes g$ has inverse $1/f\otimes 1 \otimes 1/g$ in the target, so our map factors through $(S\times_A T)_{f\otimes g}$ and we get a map $$(S\times_A T)_{f\otimes g} \to S(1)_f \otimes_{S_{(f)}} (S\times_A T)_{f\otimes g} \otimes_{T_{(g)}} T(1)_g.$$

It remains to check that the homogeneous elements of total degree one in $(S\times_A T)_{f\otimes g}$ map to homogeneous elements of the appropriate degree in $S(1)_f \otimes_{S_{(f)}} (S\times_A T)_{f\otimes g} \otimes_{T_{(g)}} T(1)_{g}$. If $(s\otimes t)/(f\otimes g)^n$ is of homogeneous degree one, then both $s/f^n$ and $t/g^n$ are too, so $s/f^n\otimes 1 \otimes t/g^n$ lies in $S(1)_f \otimes_{S_{(f)}} (S\times_A T)_{(f\otimes g)} \otimes_{T_{(g)}} T(1)_{(g)}$ and we've won.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had something like this in mind, but then I didn’t quite see how to neatly justify the well-definedness of the map your proposing. What would be a simple way of justifying this?

Comment: Apply the correct universal properties several times. Start with a map of modules out of $S_{d+1}\times T_{d+1}$, then note that this is $A$-balanced, so it descends to the tensor product $S_{d+1}\otimes_A T_{d+1}$. Next, note that $f\otimes g$ acts invertibly on the target, so the map factors through the localization at $f\otimes g$. Finally, restrict to the submodule of appropriately-graded things. This is not the interesting part of the problem.

Comment: I agree that it is not the interesting part of the problem, but I think its nonetheless important for beginners like me to be able to perform such arguments, and thats why I'm insisting. As far as I can tell, your construction only works if $f$ and $g$ are of degree one; I'm running into arithmetic problems if this is not the case. If $S$ and $T$ are generated by $S_1$ resp. $T_1$ as $A$-algebras then this suffices, but Hartshorne doesn't state this hypothesis in the Exercise. Does one have to assume this here or can it be avoided?

Comment: Could you explain where you think the argument needs $f,g$ of degree one? Maybe I'm overlooking something, but I do not see a place where we use this - I think probably $f,g$ of the same degree is all you need, which you can always arrange starting from any homogeneous $f',g'$ by raising each to the power of the degree of the other.

Comment: I edited my question to explain in detail where I'm stuck. If you find the time to go through this explanation that would be great, but no worries if not, thanks in any case!

Comment: @RedundantAunt I've written up how I would build this construction. Your difficulties seem to lie mostly in the first step where we define the map from the tensor product - the universal property I'm using here is that if we have a map of $R$-modules $f:M\times N\to Q$ which is linear in each argument, then it descends to a map of $R$-modules $\widetilde{f}:M\otimes_R N\to Q$ by $\widetilde{f}(m\otimes n)=f(m,n)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I get it now!